How to filter a JavaScript array based on matches from a MongoDB collection?
I have a mongodb collection where each document in it represent a "window" with a device_id (string), a start_time and possibly an end_time (both timestamps).
Now, given a javascript array containing objects with each object having a device_id and a timestamp, I want to construct a MongoDb query that outputs the same array but only containing objects for which there exists at least one document in the collection matching the device_id and with the timestamp being inside of its "window" (i.e. greater than the start_time and less than the end_time if end_time exists).
So given the following documents in a collection "windows":
{
  "start_time": "2024-05-12T12:00:00Z",
  "end_time": "2024-05-12T14:00:00Z",
  "device_id:": "1"
},
{
  "start_time": "2024-05-12T07:00:00Z",
  "end_time": "2024-05-12T09:00:00Z",
  "device_id:": "2"
},
{
  "start_time": "2024-05-12T01:00:00Z",
  "end_time": "2024-05-12T03:00:00Z",
  "device_id:": "3"
}


and an array like:
const timestamps = [
   { device_id: 1, timestamp: "2024-05-12T13:00:00Z"}, 
   { device_id: 3, timestamp: "2024-05-12T13:00:00Z"},
   { device_id: 4, timestamp: "2024-05-12T13:00:00Z"}
];

would result in [{ device_id: 1, timestamp: "2024-05-13T13:00:00Z"}] since this is the only item matching the criteria.
Note that I don't want to iterate over the array making one database query for each item but rather see if this can be done with only one database query.

Why not just construct a query in javascript with $or using an $and for each item in the array? Like { $or: [{ device_id: { $eq: <device_id> },  start_time: { $gte: <start_time> },  end_time: { $lte: <end_time>} }, { <iterate> }, ...] } ?

@aneroid not sure how this would result in the desired output?

why [{ device_id: 1, timestamp: "2024-05-13T13:00:00Z"}] as the endtime is also less than 2024-05-13T13:00:00Z

https://mongoplayground.net/p/_Xiha6a-ut9 this is the closest i got to but this tries to keep all the docs in the aggregation pipeline with the group so can run into memory limitations

@cmgchess my bad, updated the question with correct values

First, correcting your input data device_id: (extra colon) and the timestamps array using 2024-05-13 instead of 2024-05-12 since it wouldn't match what you expect.
The aggregation pipeline to get you the required output in a single query with $filter - use the timestamps array as the variable/replacement for the parameter to input:
db.windows.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      timestamps: {
        $filter: {
          input: [
            { device_id: 1, timestamp: "2024-05-12T13:00:00Z" },
            { device_id: 3, timestamp: "2024-05-12T13:00:00Z" },
            { device_id: 4, timestamp: "2024-05-12T13:00:00Z" }
          ],
          cond: {
            $and: [
              { $eq: ["$device_id", { $toString: "$$this.device_id" } ] },
              { $lte: ["$start_time", "$$this.timestamp"] },
              { $gte: ["$end_time", "$$this.timestamp"] }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // default for preserveNullAndEmptyArrays is false
    $unwind: "$timestamps"
  },
  { $replaceWith: "$timestamps" }
])

Mongo Playground

Alternative without filter:

Set a field timestamps matching the input array you have

in JS, you would just replace that as { $set: { timestamps: timestamps } } in the pipeline


Unwind that array
Check if the dates are in the required timestamp range.
Project/replace just the resulting timestamp item.

db.windows.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      timestamps: [
        { device_id: 1, timestamp: "2024-05-12T13:00:00Z" },
        { device_id: 3, timestamp: "2024-05-12T13:00:00Z" },
        { device_id: 4, timestamp: "2024-05-12T13:00:00Z" }
      ]
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$timestamps" },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          { $eq: ["$device_id", { $toString: "$timestamps.device_id" }] },
          { $lte: ["$start_time", "$timestamps.timestamp"] },
          { $gte: ["$end_time", "$timestamps.timestamp"] }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  { $replaceWith: "$timestamps" }
])

Mongo Playground
